# CSS selector for "tabindex > 0" elements

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select all the elements which has tabindex greater than -1 (focus-able elements). So far this is what I came up with:

```
$element.find('[tabindex]:not([tabindex < \'0\'])');
```

It does not work but instead throws an error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [tabindex < '0']
    at Function.Sizzle.error (vendor.js:1463)
...
```

This, however, works but itdoes not cover cases where tabindex < -1.

```
$element.find('[tabindex]:not([tabindex=\'-1\'])');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Selectors doesn't provide attribute selectors with numeric comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412767/css-comparison-operators/24413712#24413712), and neither does jQuery.

In this specific case, I suppose you could just exclude elements with a tabindex starting with the `-` sign (in addition to excluding elements with a tabindex of 0):

```
$element.find('[tabindex]:not([tabindex="0"]):not([tabindex^="-"])');
```

Comment: Even better would be "not starting with", or `:not([tabindex^="-"])`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for this:

```
$("[tabindex]").filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).attr("tabindex"), 10) >= 0;
})
```

Comment: yes but in my case I want to have a selector expression like that so later I can put it in a constant together with other expressions like ('[contentEditable=true]', 'a[href]', 'input:not([disabled])', etc.)

Comment: The question states: "*I am trying to select all the elements which has[sic] tabindex greater than -1*".  There was **nothing** in the question about combining expressions or using it as a variable.  Glad you got what you needed, but please include all your requirements in future questions.

Answer (score 0):

A modern solution using ES6 (without jQuery) for whom it may concern:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[tabindex]')).filter((el) => {
    return el.tabIndex >= 0;
})
```